# Python - increment function from a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, increment

I would like to create an increment function from a dataframe.
Me dataframe look like this:

```
 ___________ ___________
| Action_ID | Unique_ID |
|     4     |           |
|     3     |           |
|     2     |           |
|     1     |           |
|     4     |           |
 ___________ ___________
```

Would like to set Unique_ID egals i+1 when Action_ID egals 4. So:

```
 ___________ ___________
| Action_Id | Unique_Id |
|     4     |     1     |
|     3     |           |
|     2     |           |
|     1     |           |
|     4     |     2     |
 ___________ ___________
```

I've try this code:

```
def order_code(grp):
    i=0
    if(grp.loc[grp.first_valid_index(),'Action_Id']==4):
    i = i+1
    grp['Unique_Id']=i
return(grp)

c=(c.groupby('Action_Id')).apply(order_code)
```

But it displays me:

```
 ___________ ___________
| Action_Id | Unique_Id |
|     4     |     1     |
|     3     |           |
|     2     |           |
|     1     |           |
|     4     |     1     |
 ___________ ___________
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `i` is in the scope of the function which you're working in. If you were to do for example:

```
inc = 0
def order_code(grp):
  global inc
  if(grp.loc[grp.first_valid_index(),'Action_Id']==4):
    inc += 1
    grp['Unique_Id']=inc
  return(grp)
c=(c.groupby('Action_Id')).apply(order_code)
```

it would work.

Comment: Thanks Eli for your quick answer. However I've tried your code and it display the same as my function (1 and not an increment).